# Vimeo API OAUTH2 Not redirecting to IOS after login

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, vimeo-api, app-transport-security

I'm attempting to use the VIM NETWORKING library from Vimeo in iOS 9.2:

https://github.com/vimeo/VIMNetworking

Using the pegasus sample build, I was able to get OAUTH2 successfully login in via facebook, and then redirecting back to my app.

I was only able to achieve this after I ensure that the following entries were in my plist file (this is not documented anywhere):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
       <dict>
        <key>api.vimeo.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>vimeo.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Now this worked on a simulator with Xcode 7.2 / ios9.2, however when deploying to my phone, again 9.2 the redirect does not occur.

Is anyone aware of any other specific settings that might explain the difference between phone an simulator.

So - Question - Why is VIMEO not redirecting back to my app???

Logs from success (simulator) are as follows:

```
2015-12-21 08:53:29.724 Pegasus[13409:1982060] APP LAUNCH
2015-12-21 08:53:29.749 Pegasus[13409:1982060] VIMVimeoSession: Couldn't find         shared group URL.
2015-12-21 08:53:29.777 Pegasus[13409:1982060] --INIT
2015-12-21 08:53:29.782 Pegasus[13409:1982060] --INIT
2015-12-21 08:53:29.809 Pegasus[13409:1982060] SAVING: {
tasks =     (
);
}
 2015-12-21 08:53:29.810 Pegasus[13409:1982060] SAVING: {
 tasks =     (
 );
 }
2015-12-21 08:53:29.810 Pegasus[13409:1983597] --NEXT 0: queue complete!
2015-12-21 08:53:29.811 Pegasus[13409:1983621] --NEXT 0: queue complete!
2015-12-21 08:54:08.515 Pegasus[13409:1982060] Unable to archive account data.
2015-12-21 08:54:09.372 Pegasus[13409:1982060] Unable to archive account data.
2015-12-21 08:54:09.375 Pegasus[13409:1982060] cache start (/users/38921700)
2015-12-21 08:54:09.376 Pegasus[13409:1988481] cache failure 0.000502534 sec     (/users/38921700)
2015-12-21 08:54:09.376 Pegasus[13409:1988481] server start (/me)
2015-12-21 08:54:09.625 Pegasus[13409:1987910] server success 0.249085 sec (/me)
2015-12-21 08:54:10.660 Pegasus[13409:1982060] 0 new assets. 0 existing    descriptors. 0 assets associated
2015-12-21 08:54:10.661 Pegasus[13409:1982060] 0 new assets. 0 existing    descriptors. 0 assets associated
```

Logs from phone are as follows:

```
2015-12-21 08:55:53.629 Pegasus[266:21819] APP LAUNCH
2015-12-21 08:55:53.676 Pegasus[266:21819] VIMVimeoSession: Couldn't find shared group URL.
2015-12-21 08:55:53.711 Pegasus[266:21819] --LOAD 0
2015-12-21 08:55:53.711 Pegasus[266:21819] --INIT
2015-12-21 08:55:53.725 Pegasus[266:21819] --LOAD 0
2015-12-21 08:55:53.725 Pegasus[266:21819] --INIT
2015-12-21 08:55:53.750 Pegasus[266:21819] SAVING: {
 tasks =     (
 );
}
2015-12-21 08:55:53.751 Pegasus[266:21819] SAVING: {
 tasks =     (
 );
 }
 2015-12-21 08:55:53.754 Pegasus[266:21868] --NEXT 0: queue complete!
 2015-12-21 08:55:53.754 Pegasus[266:21869] --NEXT 0: queue complete!
```

Note - No Call back made on the phone.

Comment: Anything in your logs?

Comment: No errors at all. No callback made to the app

Comment: hi I've added the logs, I'm not sure that the keychain issue would manifest differently on the phone than the simulator?

Comment: The developers are fairly active on github. If you submit an issue you might get a quicker response.

Comment: HI thanks - yes noticed, I have some dialogue with one of them which is great. I'll be sure to keep this thread updated.